# Eclipse loading file from different project

Tags: java, eclipse, filesystems, project-management, fileinputstream

In an effort to make starting new projects easier, I've 'factored' out several classes I use regularly into a separate project in eclipse. I call this project the All-In-One. It holds a variety of abstract classes and OpenGL related methods I often reuse.

(All-In-One is included in the build path)

The issue I'm having is with another project, I'll call it the test project. I create an instance of the SimpleShader class in the test project ( referencing All-In-One ), but during runtime, it searches for default.vert and doesn't find it (java.io.FileNotFoundException)

I'm guessing it has to do with Parent Project not knowing about the shdr folder and its contents; or seeing that the class is 'created' in test project, it doesn't look in All-In-One's src folder. I've tried linking a folder to the shdr folder in the test project, but nothing changed.

```
All-In-One Project
    src/
        SimpleShader.java
        shdr/
            default.vert
            .... other files
Test Project
    src/
        Here would be the main file that creates an instance of 
        SimpleShader, which then looks for default.vert (but can't find it)
```

I load the file with this

```
String filename = "shdr/default.vert"; // It's actualy passed via a parameter, but this works.
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename); // Boom java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

Before creating a seperate project for all the major things, this worked just fine. I hope that it's just something simple that I don't know, or understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your build path look like? Why don't you use the all-in-one as a jar-library with proper versioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on what Guenther said, I had tried that already without success. I did feel inspired and found that this worked.

```
String filename = SimpleShader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toExternalForm().substring(5)+filename;
```

Outputs somthing similiar to

```
/workspace/All-In-One/bin/shdr/default.vert
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put projects on the build path, you cannot access their files directly from the file system. The referenced project will be build as a jar file and the resulting jar will be put on the build path. Hence you must load the resource you are looking from the classpath, e.g. 
    InputStream stream = TestShader.class.getResourceAsStream("path/to/resouce");

See the Api-Doc for Class.getResourceAsStream() for more information.